# Image and menu positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my menu working with an image on the left side. For some reason whenever I try to align the image in same line with the menu it's not working out. This is what the html looks like, I can't get the CSS working at all. It's either throwing the menu under the image or the background disappears and the content overlaps the menu but the image is in the right place. The image is 50px in height as well so it shouldn't be a problem.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="logo_small2.png" alt="" id="banner">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Main page</a></li>
            <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="gamemodes.html">Game modes</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header div {
    height: 50px;
    background: #333333;
}

#banner,
header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

header nav > ul > li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 12px;
    position: relative;
}
```

What happens now is that the banner is in place over the background of the div and the menu is under the banner and the background in a new line. If I replace the img with a simple h1 it works as a charm >.> I'm clueless, please help

Comment: How about creating a fiddle?

Comment: The `nav` needs to be `inline-block` too I suspect. It's currently block level and so 100% wide.

Comment: @Paulie_D I set the nav itself to be an inline-block too, now it's a bit better since it's not in a new line but still 50% under the background and the level of the image, any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS does not match the HTMl, there is no `header` shown.

Assuming that the div is, in fact the header, the nav needs to be inline-block too I suspect. It's currently block level and so 100% wide.

Then you can just align the elements.

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  background: tomato; /* for demo only */

}
header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#banner,
header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header nav > ul > li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/200/50" alt="" id="banner">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Main page</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="gamemodes.html">Game modes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Indeed the code was not complete, it's my fault. A header does exist but the menu is not the only thing in the header as I'm trying to palce a larger image above the menu which messes up the menu for some reason. Do you have a possible solution for that too?

Comment: Without an image of what you are trying to do it's hard to advise. I'd suggest asking a NEW question so as not to invalidate any answers to this one.

Answer (score -1):

Possible reason is the width of the image not allowing the inline-block comand:

try this:

```
img{ float:left; width:50%; vertical-align:middle;}
ul{float:right;width:40%;vertical-align:middle;}
```

Comment: Just guessing at arbitrary widths is not really an answer...is it?

Comment: May not be but opens a way to solve the problem in the first place if width is the issue.